# Perl regex - remove first part of dot-separated string

Tags: regex, perl

I have to remove the first part of a dot-separated string. Such as:

```
test.domain.com          --> domain.com
sub.domain.example.com   --> domain.example.com
bar.foo.bar.hoster.net   --> foo.bar.hoster.net
```

and so on...

How to do this in perl?

Comment: Go on. Give it a try. It's not as hard as you might think. But I have a suspicion this might be an `XY problem` in that you might be tripping over on domains that are `company.com` vs. `company.co.uk`

Comment: I tried it like that: $String =~ s/^.*\.(\S+)$/$1/;
But it returns only the last part...

Comment: Try $String =~ s/^.*?\.(\S+)$/$1/;

Comment: That's because your `.*` is greedy.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey. That's it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a substitution like this:

```
$str =~ s/^[^.]*\.//;
```

The regex means:

- `^` - beginning of string
- `[^.]*` - 0 or more characters that are not `.`
- `\.` - a literal dot

There's no need to capture the rest of the string just to replace it back in.

---

This code assumes that if there are no dots in the string, you want to leave it unchanged.

However, if you want `"foo"` to turn into `""`, you just need to make the `\.` optional:

```
$str =~ s/^[^.]*\.?//;
```

Answer (score 1):

A non-regex* solution might be more obvious:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @tests = (
    'test.domain.com',
    'sub.domain.example.com',
    'bar.foo.bar.hoster.net',
);

for my $t (@tests) {
    (undef, my @parts) = split(/\./, $t);
    say join('.', @parts);
}
```

Or:

```
for my $t (@tests) {
    my $i;
    say join('.', grep { ++$i > 1 } split(/\./, $t));
}
```

* Well, *mostly* non-regex, anyway. The first argument to `split` is a pattern, but we're just matching a literal dot.

Comment: @melpomene True, but...? There aren't any in the example input.

Comment: Well, they're valid in domain names. Try [https://stackoverflow.com./](https://stackoverflow.com./).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @domains = ("test.domain.com", "abc.sub.example.com");

foreach my $value (@domains) {
    $value =~ s/[^.]+.(.*)/$1/;
    print $value . "\n";
    }
```

I like using a negative character class [^.]+ (not dot) vs doing a .*?   Using .*? seems to get me in trouble from time to time, when the character class is doing what is really being asked, up to the first non dot.

Output:

```
domain.com
sub.example.com
```

Comment: There's no reason for the capture. You can get rid of it to make it simpler.